# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "en un plis plas", "en un pis pas" o "en un pispás"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Leyendo "Una educación", de Tara Westover encontré la frase:

> Una pelea a puñetazos puede acabar en un tiroteo **en un plis plas**.

Hacía tiempo que no oía la expresión, que también he oído a veces como **en un pis pas**.

En el DLE encontramos ambos:

> [**plis plas**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TQ0FsVJ)
>   `De origen expresivo`
>
> **en un plis plas**
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. en un santiamén.
>
> > [**santiamén**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XFlsFDX)
> >     `De las palabras lats. [Spiritus] Sancti, Amen '[del Espíritu] Santo, amén', con que suelen terminar algunas oraciones de la Iglesia.`
> >
> > **en un santiamén**
> >     1. loc. adv. coloq. En un instante.

> [**pis**<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TBp9fwn)
>
> **en un pis pas**
>   Véase pispás.
>
> > [**pispás**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TDHBi37)
> >
> > **en un pispás**
> >     Tb. en un pis pas.
> >
> > `De or. expr.`
> >
> > 1. loc. adv. coloq. **en un santiamén**.

Vaya, que todo lo siguiente es equivalente:

- en un pis pas
- en un pispás
- en un plis plas
- en un santiamén

Sin embargo, por vueltas que le doy al DLE lo único que hallo como origen de la expresión es *origen expresivo*. Busqué un poco y no encontré nada relevante, ¿alguien se apunta a aventurar un origen?

Comment: Como padre que soy ahora tengo experiencia en canciones de series para niños. Me hace especialmente gracia la de _Robocar Poli_, que dice "raudos van, y en un pispás, dispuestos siempre a acudir". Me fascina cómo combinan "raudos", que suena bastante formal, con "pispás", que suena muy coloquial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy capaz de encontrar gran cosa acerca de la expresión, pero por lo que he visto es bastante reciente. El caso más antiguo lo encuentro en la hemeroteca de del diario ABC, en la forma *en un "pis-pas"* (nótese el uso de las comillas, que podría indicar su reciente creación):

> *[...] y su mujer está contenta porque la limpieza se hace en un "pis pas" [...].*
>
> **ABC (Madrid).** 2 de julio de 1961, [página 75](http://hemeroteca.abc.es/nav/Navigate.exe/hemeroteca/madrid/abc/1961/07/02/075.html).

Por los ejemplos que veo, la variante *un plis plas* se originó unas dos décadas más tarde. Más allá de eso, no hay mucho más. La expresión entró en el DLE en 2001, y su "origen expresivo" indica, al igual que en el caso de otras expresiones como "pin pan", "plin plan" o "zis zas", lo siguiente (extraído de una consulta realizada a la RAE el 30/07/2015):

> Una voz expresiva es la que pretende mostrar con viveza y eficacia los sentimientos o ideas del emisor, amparándose por lo común en connotaciones afectivas, irónicas, etc.

Entiendo que, en este caso, la connotación que se quería mostrar era la de rapidez, haciendo equivaler la expresión a lo que tarda en darse dos palmadas (*plas* suele usarse como onomatopeya de las palmadas), o a lo mejor lo que tardan dos gotas en caer:

> *El agua que goteaba de las tejas hacía un agujero en la arena del patio. Sonaba: plas, plas, y luego otra vez plas, en mitad de una hoja de laurel que daba vueltas y rebotes metida en la hendidura de los ladrillos.*
>
> Juan Rulfo, "Pedro Páramo", 1955 - 1980 (México).

Es posible también que tenga un origen similar a esta otra voz anterior, recogida ya en 1936:

> **[pispa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TDDHCJv)**
>
> De la onomat. *pisp*.
>
> 1. f. Muchachita vivaracha.

Según Corominas, voces como esta y *pizpireta* 'vivaracha':

> [...] son voces de creación expresiva, que con la combinación consonántica *psp* indican la vivacidad del movimiento.

Este mismo grupo *psp* lo encontramos en *pis pas*, indicando asimismo un movimiento rápido y, por tanto, susceptible de denotar un breve espacio de tiempo.